# How can I do Math.pow with a floating point base?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

I'm doing `Math.pow(6.9, 3)` and getting `328.50900000000007` instead of `328.509`. How can I get just `328.509`?

I am referring specifically to JavaScript.

Comment: This is an artefact of how numbers are internally represented by Javascript, for converting you can use `toFixed` - so `Math.pow(6.9, 3).toFixed(3)`.

Comment: This is just a rounding error, 328.50900000000007 is the closest floating-point number to 328.509
Fore more information, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1) and [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: 328.509 cannot possibly be stored in a floating point number. This does not limit to JS, same goes to how 1/3 cannot be stored exactly in decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

So you need to `Math.pow(6.9, 3).toFixed(3)`

Comment: Maybe you should explain that this returns a string representation of the number rounded off to 3 decimals, and not another number?